# How to download RTMP stream from Stanford Math?

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, streaming, video-streaming, rtmp

I would like to download the Tadashi Tokieda lectue

https://mrc.stanford.edu/content/science-sheet-paper-0

inspecting the page, I discovered the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("stanford-video-container").setup({
        flashplayer: "/sites/default/modules/stanford/stanford_video/media/player.swf",
        image: "/sites/default/files/PL_151203-Tokieda_1.jpg",
        width: "320", height: "240",
        provider: "rtmp",
        streamer: "rtmp://sv-stream.stanford.edu/math",
        file: "120315_Tokeida.m4v",
        'plugins': {
            'captions-2': {
                 'file': "/"
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

using: rtmp://sv-stream.stanford.edu/math/120315_Tokeida.m4v

I tried saving the stream through VLC (Open Source > Network > URL), but it wouldn't play.

I then tried downloading it through rtmpdump with the following command

```
rtmpdump -r "rtmp://sv-stream.stanford.edu/math" -y "120315_Tokeida.m4v" -o ~/Desktop/tokeida.m4v
```

but got the error: **ERROR: Closing connection: NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound**

how can I download this stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there.
I took a capture from the player and saw that the object name in the stream is not merely "120315_Tokeida.m4v" but "mp4:120315_Tokeida.m4v"

The URL is then:

```
rtmp://sv-stream.stanford.edu/math/mp4:120315_Tokeida.m4v
```

mpv can display it,

edit: my version of vlc won't work correctly, sometimes it hangs sometimes it works

This command works:

```
rtmpdump -r "rtmp://sv-stream.stanford.edu/math" -y "mp4:120315_Tokeida.m4v" -o ~/Desktop/tokeida.m4v
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! :-) could you explain how you determined the object name ("capture from the player")? and the rtmp URL didn't seem to work in my VLC (Open Source > Network) so I had to use rtmpdump.

Comment: Well i ran this command: tcpdump -n -s0 -p -w /tmp/capture.cap net 171.64.0.0/14  while running the video in the flash plugin. I looked at it with wireshark and noticed that there was mp4: in front of 120315_Tokeida.m4v. I don't know if the information is embedded in the player or if there was some previous information queried. I mean I wouldn't know how to script this in case other videos at stanford aren't all of type mp4 and thus apparently with a mp4: prefix . By the way you're right. It appears VLC hangs almost immediately after the start of the video (mpv is fine)

Comment: much appreciative for providing those details!